# Unexpected long/integer value at the start of the logged message

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I'm facing an issue with log4j2, that prints a value as first part of a logged message.

I'm using the following configuration and it works as expected except for the un-wanted value:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration status="info">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="myappender-app" fileName="C:/Programs/apache-tomcat-8.5.29/logs/app.log" filePattern="C:/Programs/apache-tomcat-8.5.29/logs/%d_app.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%t]%5level %d{ISO8601}[%X{mdc-uuid} %X{sessionId}] %c{2} - %m%n%r%throwable{5}</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
   </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.mypack.app" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="myappender-app" level="debug" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The result is something like:

```
    [https-jsse-nio-18443-exec-6] INFO 2018-04-02T10:37:24,344[ ] filters.UUIDFilter - First logged message
39736[https-jsse-nio-18443-exec-6] INFO 2018-04-02T10:37:24,596[localhost-1522658244353 ] controller.MyAppController - Second Message
39988[https-jsse-nio-18443-exec-6] INFO 2018-04-02T10:37:24,602[localhost-1522658244353 ].....
39994[https-jsse-nio-18443-exec-6]ERROR 2018-04-02T10:37:54,697[localhost-1522658244353 ]....
other messages
```

The first message is correct while the others have those values [39736,39988,..] at the start of each line.

I'm assuming is something related to the rolling policy, but I could not see it in other examples using the same configuration.

Does anyone knows which is the problem and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is `%n%r%throwable{5}` in below line -

```
<pattern>[%t]%5level %d{ISO8601}[%X{mdc-uuid} %X{sessionId}] %c{2} - %m%n%r%throwable{5}</pattern>
```

- `%n` refers to new line character.
- `%r` refers to number of milliseconds elapsed since the JVM was started until the creation of the logging event.
- `%throwable{5}` refers to exception stack trace.

Because your pattern contains `%n` so it will create a new line in logs and then `%r` will log number of milliseconds (that unwanted value). Since there is no exception so `%throwable{5}` is printing nothing.

To resolve it, simply write `%n` at the end of the pattern so that a new log statement will get printed in next line. You can also remove `%r` if you do not want to print that unwanted value at all.

Comment: Solved, I totally missed the %n inside the pattern. I wrongly added the %r and %throwable{5} at the end and forgot about the new line.